# Moving UILabels to (X,Y) Position Programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios5

```
- (Unit*) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        location = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);

        self.text = @"Test Text";
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:40.0];

        self.bounds = CGRectMake(0,
                                 0,
                                 [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font].width,
                                 [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font].height);

    }
```

It works good for the sizing, but if I change the values for the first two parameters in `CGRectMake`, the `UILabel` doesn't move to that position. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a way I could move the `UILabel`'s (X,Y) a way in which I don't have to make a new `CGRectMake`() every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the CGRectMake on `self.frame`, not `bounds` if I remember correctly.

Comment: No problem. If you move that label a lot to predefined positions, you might consider using #define constant to make your job a bit easier.